# How to download file by code sent with Response.TransmitFile?

Tags: asp.net

OK, after reading some of the posts here and trying many different ways to download file sent with TransmitFile command Ive decided to write question anyway hoping someone will help me.
I have 2 pages master.aspx and client.aspx. With the master page, I am downloading and uploading files to multiple websites and that way keeping them in sync. Client pages are on those servers and they are handling downloading and uploading content on the particular site itself.
Now to download (send page) from a client page I am using this code (excerpt):

```
          Response.TransmitFile(sPath + sFileName)
          Response.Flush() ' Sends all currently buffered output To the client.
          Response.SuppressContent = True ' Gets Or sets a value indicating whether To send HTTP content To the client.
          ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() ' Causes ASP.NET To bypass all events And filtering In the HTTP pipeline chain Of execution And directly execute the EndRequest Event.
          Response.End()
```

to download that content I am using this:

```
    Using client As WebClient = New WebClient()
      SourcePath = rootDir + "UploadedFiles\"
      If Directory.Exists(SourcePath) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(SourcePath)
      End If
      client.DownloadFile(lblURL.Text + "?action=download&Path=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(SourcePath) + "&FileName=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(InputFileName) + "&AdminCode=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(cAdminCode), SourcePath + InputFileName)
    End Using
```

But all that I am getting is the HTML content of client.aspx page, it seems that client.DownloadFile can't figure out that I want to download a file not that page itself. How to make client.DownloadFile to download file sent with TransmitFile?

Thanks,
Dejan

**UPDATE**:
I have found an issue with my path variables, because Ive changed to DownloadFile that has two parameters (second target file path), I was wrongly sending the target file as a parameter to the remote procedure and that's why didn't get the file.

Comment: You don't need to use `Flsuh` or `SuppressContent` with `TransmitFile`. You should avoid using `Response.Flush` and `Response.End` anyway (as they wreck havoc with the HTTP pipeline). The reason you're seeing HTML content in the response is because you have other code elsewhere that is writing to the response stream - using `Response.End` is just hiding that. You need to audit your entire page's lifecycle and code path to find out where it's being written.

Comment: Also, you should consider using an `*.ashx` `@Handler`) file instead of `.aspx` `(`@Page`) to return binary content to consumers as it gives you more control over the response _and_ it's faster because it doesn't invoke any of the WebForms Page Lifeycle code.

Comment: Thanks Dai, I will try that way, many thanks

Comment: @Dai, ok Ive changed to asxh file, but the result is the same (except now I have nothing), I can't get the file, I am sure that the problem is how to get it more than how to send it...

Comment: Please post more code - it's hard to tell what's going on. Please post your entire `*.ashx` and `*.ashx.cs` file - and your client code.

Comment: @Dai thanks for your support, with you I've found the problem by recreating two simple pages and then I saw the issue caused by wrongly used path variable that was pointed to unexisting files.